# How to verify html5 Validation with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify a validation, can be seen here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/sUy6IKpQsHw, this link is not mine but I want to verify this text `Please fill out this field.`, or any other better idea ? how to verify it

What I did is as below:

```
msg = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
print(msg.get_attribute("value"))
time.sleep(10)
assert msg.get_attribute("value") == "Please fill out this field."
```

Print has given following output `>       print(msg.get_attribute("value"))` and assert has given `AssertionError`, I have been through many answers non helped me

HTML:

```
<input name= "username" id="username" required>
```

I tried `[print(msg.get_attribute("value").values)` to see whats there and it has given following error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: @DebanjanB non of that is python solution, any idea of python solution ?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes I found the solution but it gives following error

username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.cell.small-21.form-text.required#edit-name[name='username']")))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="c11d47f6c9de7f2445f21840a8223d95")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable object at 0x0000000005147E80>
message = ''

Comment: @DebanjanB actually I have your line of code , in my case name of field was username, so I replaced and tried, I am sorry I dun have any idea of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To verify the presence of the [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) *validation message* with text as **Please fill out this field.** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username[name='username']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "input[@id='username' and @name='username']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `validationMessage` attribute to get validation message:

```
msg = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
validation_message = msg.getAttribute("validationMessage")
# or
# validation_message = self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].validity.valid;", msg)

assert validation_message == "Please fill out this field."
```

Answer (score 0):

FOllwoing should work

```
username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
assert username.get_attribute("validationMessage") == "Please fill out this field."
```